# Does font choice affect SEO other than through usability?

Tags: seo, fonts

Does my choice of font have any influence on natural search engine results?

Is using a Web Safe font better for SEO?
What about the use of imported fonts?

I am not talking about user experience here that can have an impact on SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I have a great deal of certainty that it is all about usability when it comes to fonts.

There is a easy to overlook usability issue ... that when the font changes its size / space it uses it can cause a reflow page repaint for the above the fold portion of the page. This is read by google as page was not ready to be used before the redraw, (a SEO usability issue).

If the font change is to headline tags, this can be corrected by giving the headline tag a height and width larger than it needs to not trigger the repaint on the entire page.

The basic idea is to contain the redraw into a block so that it does not reflow the entire page. The how to is based on the specifics of the your page and CSS you are using. But you want to both get material painted onto the screen and avoid the change from moving that material. Giving the fastest time for the page to be usable and page reflowing is not usable. Its about how much of the page must be repainted.

Creative design use of empty space under text that changes can be your friend.

---

Additional Resources.

[1] Chrome Dev tools can be used to aid in good rendering ... https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/rendering/performance/

[2] SEJ interview "Google's Martin Splitt explains rendering and how it impacts SEO" ... https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-rendering-seo/

[3] There is an old video from google when google started on user experience ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHxbs5WEQzE

Comment: Can you elaborate more - the way you have answered does not really  to answer the question as asked, although it hints at some answers.

Comment: @davidgo I don't believe there can be a single answer on how to deal with repainting in the browser. The headline tag is the most obvious, and easiest to point towards the solution ... If the redraw to reflow were in columnized text for example maybe a default font has the same width? ... If the reflow is only happening when the line breaks to two lines on a mobile device not at desktop maybe a media rule and using none breakable space so the word does not jump to the next line when the font changes ...

Answer (score -1):

I think that the choice of font affects the usability, because if a person is not convenient to perceive the content, it will simply leave the site, so I think that it is necessary to pick up the font that suits everyone, if you want to change the standard font.... To some extent, the seo it affects because if the site will quickly leave users, the search engines may pay attention to this